# How to get input keyboard language in current active form using vb.net?

Tags: input

I tried to use
`RichTextBox1.Text = Application.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName`

if my FORM1 is now on "US" language but my current application that I focus on is in "JPN" language.
This Code detect only language in FORM1 so I get "US" in my `richtextbox`. (that is wrong, I should get "JPN" from my current application that I now focus on)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Though your question is little bit difficult to understand**
I tried from my side....
This Might help you :

```
Dim myCurrentLanguage As InputLanguage = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage
   RichTextBox1.Text = myCurrentLanguage.Culture.EnglishName & ControlChars.Cr
```